# How do the quest reward items scale in Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode?

Tags: borderlands-2

In Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode, enemies and quest rewards scale with the player's level. But when exactly is the level of the quest rewards determined, upon accepting or completing the corresponding quest?

Let's say I accept a side quest at level 60, but don't finish it until my character is on level 65. Will the quest reward be level 60 or  level 65?

I've searched this site and the wiki, but couldn't find a definite answer for UVHM, only for TVHM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/638784-borderlands-2/69105003) the quest rewards' scaling is determined at the time you *activate* the quest:

> Only the activation level counts.
>
> You could accept/start the quest at level 50, not turn it in until level 72, but the quest reward item would still be level 50.
>
> So once in UVHM it's better either not to do any side quests with blue or unique rewards until you reach the level cap.

I can confirm that this how the scaling works for UVHM, as well.

Comment: Granted, VHM and TVHM tend to use a "ratchet" system where the base level of quests and their rewards changes every X levels (8, I think).  So, you may get level 34 quests/rewards when you're level 38.  In UVHM, quests and their rewards are always the same level you are when you start the quest.